# How to go offline in Team Server Foundation in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

Sometime we need to do same page changes in different user then we got problem that file is in lock and cannot do changes.what my plan was go offline and make changes and then after do the changes go on-line and merge it.How do you accomplish this ?as like my way or you have other way of doing that ?If you use my way,are there any easy way to go offline in visual studio.many thanks.(I am using visual studio 2012 and tfs 2012)

Answer (score 8):

Two options that I know of:

1. Use the command-line utility in [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f).
2. Use the Go Offline extension (for Visual Studio [2010](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/425f09d8-d070-4ab1-84c1-68fa326190f4?SRC=Home), [2012](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e7e28e0d-02a2-4497-bcdc-5953ba23f7dc), [2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6e54271c-2c4e-4911-a1b4-a65a588ae138), [2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a7cb3430-eb4a-4cc9-9533-c7afaef163de))

Answer (score 7):

The straightforward way is just disable the network and re-open your solution. Then everything will go offline.

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended that you enable multiple checkout in such case. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607039/multiple-checkout-with-team-foundation-server) to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Visual Studio extension for going offline.
[Tfs Go-Offline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JanStuchlik.TfsGo-Offline)

Answer (score 0):

It may not solve the problem with the lock, but you can use a "local workspace" and use the files easily offline.[MSDN Article about "Decide between using a local or a server workspace".](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx)
The problem with the lock should be solved by just not setting a lock, if that's possible.